# remove strings from array after uncheck the chekbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've data for my checkbox here,

```
$scope.dataList = {
    'ICT': true,
    'OTTIX_DT': true,
    'CP EMR AD': true,
}
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="miniAddons.dataList[data.jobName]" 
ng-change="pickExtra($event,'miniAddons', chosenMiniAddons, data.jobName);">

$scope.pickExtra = function(evt,JBname,chosenMiniAddons,chosenOptions){
    
    $scope.userSelectedMiniAddon = Object.keys($scope[miniAddons].dataList);

}
```

my scenario is to disable/enable button, so using `var temp = Object.keys($scope.dataList)` that gives me like `['ICT','OTTIX_DT','CP EMR AD']` followed by that I can check the `.length` of the array, based on array length, if `length > 0` I'd enable the button
otherwise disable it.

Whenever, I click on checkbox, array item getting increased as expected, but don't know how to remove items when uncheck the check box.

in simple words, if all goes `false` in `$scope.dataList` i need to disable button, i should enable button if atleast on key has `true` value.

**currently using pure old JS, not event any latest es6** , so had confusion how to use filter and map together in pure old js.

Kindly someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit difficult to help you with the current information of the question, but I have a feeling that your checklist does not shrink because the key is not deleted from your array

Try to use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your Object.keys(yourData)

```
$scope.dataList = {
    'ICT': true,
    'OTTIX_DT': true,
    'CP EMR AD': true,
}
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="miniAddons.dataList[data.jobName]" 
ng-change="pickExtra($event,'miniAddons', chosenMiniAddons, data.jobName);">

$scope.pickExtra = function(evt,JBname,chosenMiniAddons,chosenOptions){
    // Will filter out each option that is false, so the list will be empty if all are uncheked
    $scope.userSelectedMiniAddon = Object.keys($scope[miniAddons].dataList).filter((key => {
      if($scope[miniAddons].dataList[key]) { // check if the value is true.
        return key;
      }
    });

}
```